# Meaningful error logs of obfuscated node.js code

Tags: node.js, obfuscation, error-logging, deobfuscation

For the code security I have obfuscated my node.js project. Assuming that it is being used by a customer, I want to have meaningful error logs for the sake of debugging. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You could counteract the lack of relevant line numbers with error handling that specifies which part of the application the error originated from, that + the minified source and line/col number should be enough to help you track down issues.

Comment: Could also try something like this: https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support though i've never used that, so i have no idea how well something like that would work for obfuscated node.js code.